# Get first entry from MySQL database in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Could you please help me? I just want to take the first row of a table in a mysql database via Visual Basic. I prefer simple code. The only thing i found is using a while, thing that i dont want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's your issue? The sql query or connecting vb to your server or what?

Comment: what have you tried so far? there is plenty of tuts you can find on  google to connect a DB and run a query like `select fields from table limit 0, 1`

Comment: yes but i cannot show them

Comment: ok i fixxed it i didnt had made a mysql conn i made an sql one :P

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Try
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT first_row FROM test_table WHERE id = 1"
    Dim cmd as OleDbCommand
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, Reconnect)
    Dim itmReader as SqlDataReader
    itmReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If itmReader.Read Then
        Dim firstRowData as String
        firstRowData = itmReader.Item("first_row")
        MessageBox.Show(firstRowData)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 1.... may also be an option, add an ORDER BY clause to make sure you get what you are expecting.